# Spring 3.1 Missing ServletContext

Tags: spring, testing

I am trying to write an integration test for my spring application.  All my spring beans are defined in an xml file, so I am using profiles to parse them out.

Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = GenericXmlContextLoader.class, locations = {"classpath:/spring/spring-config.xml"})   
@Profile("dev")
public class AccountDAOTest {

   private EmbeddedDatabase database;

   @Autowired
   AccountDAO accountDAO;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {

      System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
      database = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).setName("memdb")
                                              .addScript("classpath:resources/createAccount.sql").build();
      Assert.assertNotNull(database);
   }

   @Test
   public void testFind() throws Exception {
      List<Account> accounts = accountDAO.findAll();
   }
}
```

My spring-config.xml is just a standard configuration file

```
<beans>
  <beans profile="prod" >
  <context:annotation-config/>
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTX" proxy-target-class="true"/>
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
...
 <beans profile="prod" >
<transaction managers, httprequests and such > 
</beans>
<!-- end of production beans -->
<!-- the following are for local testing -->
<beans profile="dev" >
</beans>
 <transaction managers and such > 
<!-- end of local testing beans -->
</beans>
```

My spring version is 3.1.Release  for spring-test, spring-transaction, spring.web.servlet, spring.web
As I am using servlet 2.5 I cannot use the newer Spring MVC configuration

When I try and run my test I get the following exception:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping()]
>   threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to
>   configure default servlet handling
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is
>   required to configure default servlet handling

I can't figure out:

1. Why the servlet is required when I don't use it explicitly for tests
2. How to get the test servlet context loaded for xml without using spring mvc

Answer (score 1):

Split the spring context config into root (non-web-related beans) and mvc (web-related beans) parts, or create a separate test config xml.